# Azure key vault: import pkcs12

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Is there any limitation in importing pkcs12 into Azure key vault, basically I need to import a root CA cert, intermediate CA cert and a leaf cert and its private key in a single file. Is this possible with Azure key vault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure KeyVault, certificates can be imported in either PFX or PEM format, so the formats you mentioned won't work unless you convert them to PEM or PFX.

Here are some [instructions](https://gist.github.com/shahdhiren/9ca059ac0762f7ef0fcf71a79ed5b022) for how to do that.

See more information about importing KeyVault certificates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates).

Comment: A PFX extension _is_ a PKCS12 formatted file, so I don't think the statement that the formats need converting is necessarily correct.